# How to write an IF condition in Google Appscript to trigger an event only if cell has been active > 2 days from the time it was first filled up

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to trigger some actions in google spreadsheet. I would like to add in a IF condition in google appscript whereby the function will only be triggered when a particular cell has been active > 2 days from the time since it was first filled up. How should I write it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I thought of another alternative which was to create two time/date stamps for two cells and compare the difference between them. There should be a simpler solution but I've been searching for days.

Comment: I believe writing timestamps is your only option to make this work, as far as I know, there's no way to grab the time a cell was last active.

Answer (score 0):

You could set an onEdit trigger and then write the timestamp on any cell so it gets stored, the you just have to check the days past since that timestamp.